# Elevator level indicator light problems Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm having a really hard time trying to build a portion of a game in unreal. I want a light in the main game to be activated based on where the elevator is. Furthermore, I can't figure out how to turn on and off a light outside the elevator event graph and blueprint from the script that makes it go up and down

The flow is basically this:

When `q` is pushed on the keyboard then the elevator comes down, BUT before the elevator comes down, I want the light to activate on the floor the person is on, showing that the elevator is coming down.
Then, when the elevator arrives, the light turns off and the elevator doors open.

Cannot control the light to turn on and off because it is not in the elevator blueprint, but theoretically should be able to because a light switch blueprint can control light that is in game but not in blueprint.

Really confused right now why it is not working!
Message #general

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**

Answer (score 0):

Add exposed variables of your FloorLight blueprint type to your elevator blueprint for each floor the Elevator could be on.
Add each FloorLight to each level and select it in the proper slot of the elevator BP.

Activate and deactivate the light BP from the elevator BP at the correct times.